# Parse json geometry data in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I exported a model from Blender using the three.js exporter, and managed to load it correctly using the JSONLoader. But I need now to store the JSON information in a variable and parse it to display the model, without loading an external file.

According to the docs, I could do it using the parse function from the GeometryLoader (http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/docs/56/#Reference/Loaders/GeometryLoader), but I checked the source at github and saw that it doesn't exist. I'm not sure wether the documentation is outdated or serving as a guide for future implementations, and could find no further information on how to do this parsing. Does anybody have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the JSONLoader you have the method `createModel` that should do what you want: this method is called by `loadAjaxJSON` when the JSON data string has been retrieved by the Ajax request.

The `createModel` method has this signature:

```
createModel  = function ( json, callback, texturePath )
```

Comment: Just tried it, worked perfectly! Just trying to work out the textures now. Thanks a lot!